# Firebase Cloud Function - Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem during deploy the functions into Cloud Function. I do believe before I put the `const admin = require('firebase-admin')` and `admin.initializeApp()` there will be a problem after I place these two, but before I place the two-line there is no problem occurred.

This is my full code for index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
  
    await admin.firestore().collection("users").add(user);
  
    res.status(201).send();
});

exports.user = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the second part to your `package.json`:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    }
}
```

Comment: your meaning is 'package.json'?

Answer (score 0):

**"parser": "babel-eslint"** - add this to your.eslintrc.js and run **npm install babel-eslint --save** this will resolve the issue.